# Slow query with joined derived tables

Tags: mysql, performance, join, explain

I have a few queries on a "custom dashboard" of my application, and one of them is taking 10-12 seconds to execute. Using EXPLAIN I can see why it's slow, but I don't know what to do about it. Here is the query:

```sql
SELECT person.PersonID,FullName,Furigana,qualdate FROM person
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT pq.PersonID,MAX(ContactDate) AS qualdate FROM person pq
    INNER JOIN contact cq ON pq.PersonID=cq.PersonID
    WHERE cq.ContactTypeID IN (22,26,45) GROUP BY pq.PersonID
  ) qual ON person.PersonID=qual.PersonID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT pe.personID,MAX(ContactDate) AS elimdate FROM person pe
    INNER JOIN contact ce ON pe.PersonID=ce.PersonID WHERE ce.ContactTypeID IN (25,31,30,41,23,42,2,33,35,29,12)
    GROUP BY pe.PersonID
  ) elim ON qual.PersonID=elim.PersonID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT po.personID FROM person po
    INNER JOIN percat pc ON po.PersonID=pc.PersonID WHERE pc.CategoryID=38
  ) overseas ON qual.PersonID=overseas.PersonID
  WHERE (elimdate IS NULL OR qualdate > elimdate)
  AND qualdate < CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 DAY
  AND overseas.PersonID IS NULL
  ORDER BY qualdate
```

And here is the EXPLAIN result:

```
id  select_type  table        type    possible_keys           key         key_len  ref                      rows  Extra
1   PRIMARY      <derived2>   ALL     NULL                    NULL        NULL     NULL                     5447  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY      <derived3>   ALL     NULL                    NULL        NULL     NULL                     5565  Using where
1   PRIMARY      <derived4>   ALL     NULL                    NULL        NULL     NULL                     9     Using where; Not exists
1   PRIMARY      person       eq_ref  PRIMARY                 PRIMARY     4        qual.PersonID            1     
4   DERIVED      pc           ref     PRIMARY,CategoryID      CategoryID  4                                 8     
4   DERIVED      po           eq_ref  PRIMARY                 PRIMARY     4        kizuna_misa.pc.PersonID  1     Using index
3   DERIVED      pe           index   PRIMARY                 PRIMARY     4        NULL                     5964  Using index
3   DERIVED      ce           ref     PersonID,ContactTypeID  PersonID    4        kizuna_misa.pe.PersonID  1     Using where
2   DERIVED      pq           index   PRIMARY                 PRIMARY     4        NULL                     5964  Using index
2   DERIVED      cq           ref     PersonID,ContactTypeID  PersonID    4        kizuna_misa.pq.PersonID  1     Using where
```

I'm sure the first line of the EXPLAIN reveals the problem (comparing with similar queries, it appears that the second line isn't too slow), but I don't know how to fix it. I already have indexes on every column that appears in the joins, but since the tables are `<derived2>` etc., I guess indexes are irrelevant.

The objective (since it's probably not obvious to someone unfamiliar with my application and schema) is a followup tickler list - if one of the #22/26/45 contacts has occurred but nothing has been done in response (either one of several other contacts or designating by a category assignment that the person is overseas), then the person should appear in the list for followup after waiting a week. Subqueries are easier for me to write and understand than these messy joins, but I can't check the sequence of dates (and subqueries are often slow, also).

#### EDIT (in response to Rick James):

MySQL version is 5.0.95 (yeah, I know...). And here is `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the three tables involved, even though most of the fields in `person` are irrelevant:

```
CREATE TABLE `contact` (
 `ContactID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `PersonID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 `ContactTypeID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 `ContactDate` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
 `Description` text,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`ContactID`),
 KEY `ContactDate` (`ContactDate`),
 KEY `PersonID` (`PersonID`),
 KEY `ContactTypeID` (`ContactTypeID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16901 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `percat` (
 `PersonID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 `CategoryID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`PersonID`,`CategoryID`),
 KEY `CategoryID` (`CategoryID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `person` (
 `PersonID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `FullName` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
 `Furigana` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
 `Sex` enum('','M','F') character set ascii NOT NULL default '',
 `HouseholdID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 `Relation` varchar(6) character set ascii NOT NULL default '',
 `Title` varchar(6) NOT NULL default '',
 `CellPhone` varchar(30) character set ascii NOT NULL default '',
 `Email` varchar(70) character set ascii NOT NULL default '',
 `Birthdate` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
 `Country` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
 `URL` varchar(150) NOT NULL default '',
 `Organization` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
 `Remarks` text NOT NULL,
 `Photo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
 `UpdDate` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`PersonID`),
 KEY `Furigana` (`Furigana`),
 KEY `FullName` (`FullName`),
 KEY `Email` (`Email`),
 KEY `Organization` (`Organization`,`Furigana`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6063 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

#### Attempted suggestion:

I tried to implement Rick James's suggestion of putting the subselects in the field list (I didn't even know that was possible), like this:

```
SELECT
  p.PersonID,
  FullName,
  Furigana,
  (SELECT MAX(ContactDate) FROM contact cq
    WHERE cq.PersonID=p.PersonID
    AND  cq.ContactTypeID IN (22,26,45))
  AS qualdate,
  (SELECT MAX(ContactDate) FROM contact ce
    WHERE ce.PersonID=p.PersonID
    AND ce.ContactTypeID IN (25,31,30,41,23,42,2,33,35,29,12))
  AS elimdate
FROM person p
WHERE (elimdate IS NULL OR qualdate > elimdate)
AND qualdate < CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 DAY
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM percat WHERE CategoryID=38 AND percat.PersonID=p.PersonID)
ORDER BY qualdate
```

But it complains: `#1054 - Unknown column 'elimdate' in 'where clause'` According to the docs, WHERE clauses are interpreted before field lists, so this approach isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an interesting query.  I am not sure what the best solution is.  Here are two guesses:

**Plan A**

```
INDEX(qualdate)
```

may help.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

This construct optimizes poorly:

```
FROM ( SELECT ... )
JOIN ( SELECT ... )
```

In your case, `overseas` should probably turned into a `JOIN`, not a subselect.  And the other two should probably be turned into a different flavor of dependent subquery:

```
SELECT  ..., 
        ( SELECT MAX(...) ... )  AS qualdate,
        ( SELECT MAX(...) ... )  AS elimdate
    FROM ...
```

What version of MySQL are you running?

**Plan B**

If practical, fold these into the subqueries so that they generate fewer rows, thereby leading to less effort at the outer query.  (One per subquery)

```
elimdate IS NOT NULL
qualdate < CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 DAY
overseas.PersonID IS NOT NULL
```

Perhaps the `NULL` tests apply to `LEFT` and this suggestion may not apply.

Comment: Plan A: (1) How can I make an index on a field that doesn't actually exist (the result of a subquery)? (2) See my edited question for my attempt to do what you suggested. Plan B: I don't understand what you're saying - I can't use the results of the subqueries inside the subqueries. I also edited my question with the additional info you asked for.

Comment: Start by removing `WHERE (elimdate IS NULL OR qualdate > elimdate)` and see if it works.  If it doesn't, we can discuss whether something needs to be added to the subquery, or whether a `HAVING` is needed outside.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by, "...see if it works." As I expected, MySQL didn't stop complaining until I removed both that line and the next (`AND qualdate < CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 DAY`), and removing those two lines naturally destroyed the whole purpose of this query - it took just as long to execute and returned 5,957 rows, whereas the correct number should be 87.

Comment: Sorry, I should have suggested removing `(elimdate IS NULL OR qualdate > elimdate) AND`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that - I did keep the syntax correct. But as long as there is any reference to elimdate or qualdate in the WHERE clause, it complains  of it being an unknown column, because at the time WHERE is interpreted, those two aliases don't exist yet.

Comment: If an alias "does not exist yet" in a `WHERE`, that is a clue that it needs to be moved to `HAVING`.  (I probably messed up my example in this way.)

Comment: How can I use `HAVING` if there is no `GROUP BY`? You mentioned your "example", but the code fragments you mentioned are too small for me to understand how you have in mind for me to use the fragments.

Comment: Column names are known to `WHERE`; computed things (via `GROUP BY` or subqueries) are known to `HAVING`.

Comment: I didn't know `HAVING` can be for the result of a subquery (I thought it always paired with `GROUP BY`). So I split the criteria into the parts based on computed things vs. columns: `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM percat WHERE CategoryID=38 AND percat.PersonID=p.PersonID) HAVING (elimdate IS NULL OR qualdate > elimdate) AND qualdate < CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 DAY`. That executed in 495ms. Thanks!

Comment: I tried also moving `AND qualdate < CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 DAY` inside the subquery (changing the name to `ContactDate`, of course), but it returned too many rows, including rows that had no contact at all. I don't see why it does that. But leaving it in the `HAVING` is good enough - I'll go with the half-second solution.